# probability of randomly selected vector being orthogonal to atleast one vector from given list of random vectors in $n$ dimensional space

Tags: probability, vectors

Let $r = {[r_1, r_2, ..., r_n]}^T, r_i \in Z^+, r_i\le 1000000$
($r$ is uniformly randomly generated $n-\text{dimensional}$ vector with non-negative integer cordinates)

Let $u = {[u_1, u_2, ..., u_n]}^T, u_i \in Z, -2\le u_i \le 2$

Now, we have $n^2$ such vectors like $u$. Let's call list containing all of them $L$.

What is the probability (in terms of $n$) of $r$ being orthogonal to some vector $v\in L$?

Comment: Each $u_i$ can take the $5$ possible values $-2,-1,0,1,2$. So number of such vectors $u$ will be $5^n$.

Comment: Is the vound on $r_i$ really necessary?

Comment: yes, becuase otherwise I suspect probability will be zero

Comment: yes all possible $u_i$ can be upto $5^n$ but we have chosen $n^2$ such $u$ to work with which makes a list $L$

Comment: ALso if $r$ is orthogonal to $v\in L$ then so is $cr$ for any positive constant $c$. So if you  bound $r_i$, then the denominator of the probability will be finite, but the numerator will be infinite.

Comment: but even if $cr$ is orthogonal we can't consider it as it will not fit in $r_i <= 1000000$. So I think we don't have that problem. And here all sample spaces are finite I think.

Comment: you are right, I forgot $r_i$ has to be integers